# Can I make another languages' out parameters work nicely in scala?

Tags: scala, native

I'm interfacing scala to some native code (through java+jna) and am about to rewrite the api using tuples and multiple return parameters. But I'm wondering if there's a better way (with implicits or something).

For example, I may have a method signature like

```
MyLib.__stdcall aMethod(String inParam, String[] out1, int[] out2);
```

Where the arrays are there so I can get the values in java:

```
String[] out1 = new String[1];
Int[] out2 = new Int[1];

lib.aMethod("in", out1, out2);

String theRealOut1Value = out1[0];
Int theRealOut2Value = out2[0];
```

and Voila! How simple!

I'm pretty sure the only reasonable thing to do is make a wrapper with a (scala) method sig like:

```
aMethodWrapper(in : String) : (String, Int)
```

*I'm not hopeful, but I'm seeing magic at every turn in scala, so I was wondering :)*

Comment: I would change the title and tags. The main point is not really c++ but scala magic :)

Comment: Do you want to rewrite `aMethod` or just how a wrapper for this could be? Just put the above code in `aMethodWrapper` and return in a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the following helper function:

```
def call[A](f: Array[A] => Unit)(implicit m: Manifest[A]): A = {
  val outA = new Array[A](1)
  f(outA)
  outA(0)
}
```

...and for two arguments:

```
def call[A, B](f: (Array[A], Array[B]) => Unit)
             (implicit m1: Manifest[A], m2: Manifest[B]): (A,  B) = {
  val outA = new Array[A](1)
  val outB = new Array[B](1)
  f(outA, outB)
  (outA(0), outB(0))
}
```

After that you may call the library functions like this:

```
call[String](lib.aMethod("foo", _))
```

and

```
call[String, Int](lib.bMethod("bar", 1, _, _))
```

Comment: Aha! Magic! that's what I was thinking about after my answer... I'll think about some more, but you're probably getting the tick :)

Comment: I'd seen it in one of the blog/tutorials I've read, but forgot about it. Probably because I only half understood the wild cards, and still don't understand those implicits and `f => Unit`. But that doesn't matter now; I've used this pattern 3 times and can declare I've found my new (sledge)-hammer!

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured it out. Declare a reference type and have implicit conversions:

```
class Ref[T : Manifest] {
  val reference = new Array[T](1);  
}

implicit def ref2Array[T : Manifest](ref :Ref[T]) : Array[T] = ref.reference;
implicit def ref2Object[T: Manifest](ref : Ref[T]) : T = ref.reference(0);
```

This allows me to write the above code as follows

```
def aMethodWrapper(in : String) : (String, Int) = {
    val out1 = new Ref[String];
    val out2 = new Ref[Int];

    lib.aMethod(in, out1, out2);
    (out1, out2);
}
```

I think this reads a whole heap nicer than before, and indicates what the parameters are there for.

If someone can offer an improved result, I'll give you a tick.

Comment: `lib.aMethod` is Java right? You can then just define to Arrays: `val out1 = new Array[String](1); val out2 = new Array[Int](1)`. You can call the Method with this: `lib.aMethod(in, out1, out2); (out1(0), out2(0))` instead using a `Ref` class.

Comment: But that's more typing, as well as being a bit obscure in the api. I'm not a java newbie, but my first `ListObjects(Object[] outParam)` use led me to "guess" that the out param should be indexed at 10 for initial safety (I knew there were going to be at most 3 items). There's around 50 methods in this api...

Comment: So you want it to be more generic? How does another method signature look like?

Answer (score 2):

```
def aMethodWrapper(in : String) : (String, Int) = {
    val out1 = new Array[String](1);
    val out2 = new Array[Int](1);

    lib.aMethod(in, out1, out2);
    (out1(0), out2(0));
}
```